# Access variables of other objects of the same class

Tags: c++, class, oop, private

I'm looking for a way to access access variables of other objects of the same class in the best way (in terms of security and efficiency).

For example, i have a `Point` class containing coordinates, the objects of which should be able to calculate the distance to other points.

```
class Point {
public:
    calc_distance(?);
private:
    double mXCoord, mYCoord;
};
```

I can do this by making the coordinates public and calculate the distance outside of this class of course, but isn't there a better way?

Comment: Just pass another `Point` parameter to `calc_distance()`. You can access it's `mXCoord` and `mYCoord` there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Public data members is not a good practice. Use a getter function like this:

```
class Point {
public:
    double getX() { return mXCoord; }
    double getY() { return mYCoord; }
private:
    double mXCoord, mYCoord;
};
```

---

Of course, as πάντα ῥεῖ said, you can pass an object of the class `Point` to your function, like this:

```
double calc_distance(Point point);
```

or better yet, avoid the copying, by passing a reference:

```
double calc_distance(Point& point);
```

Comment: Not directly related to the question, bur I have been wondering this for some time: Would you really use getter and setter for a point class?